# Using Mocha to test higher order components in React

Tags: testing, reactjs, mocha.js, higher-order-functions, enzyme

I am using a [HOC](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_higher_order_components.htm) in a React component that looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import Wrapper from 'wrapper';
class Component extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div className='component' />
    )
  };
}
export default Wrapper(Component)
```

When testing Component using Mocha I am attempting to look for a class name that should be contained within Component. Like so:

```
describe('Component', function () {
  it('can be mounted with the required class', function () {
    const component = shallow(
      <Component />
    );
    expect(component).to.have.className('component');
  });
});
```

The problem is that Mocha doesn't know to look within the wrapper for the Component and attempts to find it in the HOC. Which of course it will not.

The error I am receiving is:

```
AssertionError: expected <Wrapper(Component) /> to have a 'component' class, but it has undefined
     HTML:

     <div class="component">
     </div>
```

How do I tell Mocha to look within the HOC for the correct location of the class name instead of the HOC itself?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that you're using `shallow` instead of `mount`.

Comment: Actually, your test passes for me.

Comment: What is that wrapper package? I changed the css class to be "component2" to force the test to fail, and then it tells me `AssertionError: expected <Component /> to have a 'component2' class, but it has 'component'`. Note the lack of word wrapper like your message has: `<Wrapper(Component) />`.

Comment: Using mount instead of shallow produces
```Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element.```

The wrapper package is `react-onclickoutside` so it makes sense to get the above error as the package doesn't mount any DOM objects.

It looks like this in the DOM:
```<Wrapper(Component)>
    <Component />
</Wrapper(Component)>```

Comment: Do you know that shallow only renders one level of React components deep? That's the difference with shallow and mount. But it sounds like you have parts of your project that you're not explaining. Perhaps post a sample to github/gist?

Comment: You could consider my answer as the best answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use enzyme [.dive()](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.md)

```
const component = shallow(<Component />).dive();

expect(component.props().className).toEqual('component')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the use of Enzyme's `shallow` instead of `mount`, which is required when testing HOC's.

**So, use `mount`.**

I added this to a github project so you can see. Use my [redux-form-test](https://github.com/tylercollier/redux-form-test/tree/c53d78c546d7f3dc4484f9b671667f8a666de808) project and be sure to use the `stackoverflow-question-38106763` branch. See the `tests/unit/index.js` file.

> Be sure to read the source code of the test file. One of tests fails intentionally to reproduce your issue.

What's tricky in this situation is that the render method of the HOC exactly replicates the component it's wrapping. See the `render` method [in the source of the react-onclickoutside component you mention](https://github.com/Pomax/react-onclickoutside/blob/81d8b06f5d55d639a38e0779b7681c24c0befd0b/index.js#L190). That's why the `AssertionError` you see is confusing: it shows you HTML that looks like it's satisfying the assertion. However, if you run

```
console.log(component.debug())
```

before your `expect`, it'll show

```
<Component />
```

That's because `shallow` only goes one level deep. And enzyme is not using the rendered HTML for the assertion, it's using the React elements, which does not have the `component` class on it, as you can see.

Comment: Thanks, Tyler! I didn't test your answer but I'll mark it as accepted as it seems to be what the issue is. I appreciate the time you took in answering this. Gotta love Phoenicians helping (former)Phoenicians!